# How to build an image object in PIL/Python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have a list of 3-item tuples that is the result of list(PIL.Image.getdata()).

How do I do the opposite: build a PIL.Image object from this list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output of `getdata()` does not include the image format or the size, so you'll need to preserve those (or get the information some other way).  Then do this, using the [`putdata()`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.putdata) method:

```
# get data from old image (as you already did)
data = list(oldimg.getdata())

# create empty new image of appropriate format
newimg = Image.new(format, size)  # e.g. ('RGB', (640, 480))

# insert saved data into the image
newimg.putdata(data)
```

Comment: For my scenario, I know the image size apriori, so I didn't include that detail in my question. I agree that your comment about this is valid, a list is unidimensional after all, so the PIL internals must be told how to treat the list as bidimensional array. Thank you.